# An alternative to "serious business"

Tags: phrase-requests, colloquialisms

I am writing an article about a fancy cocktail bar and I am looking for an alternative to the phrase *"drinking here is a **serious business**"*. Normally I am pretty good at this but, I just have the same phrase floating around my head and I can't get rid of it. I am sure you will all have some excellent suggestions!

Comment: I think this question could be improved if you elaborated more on what you are trying to say. "Serious business" is a rather common expression that could mean a few different things.

Answer (score 1):

Drinking here is: a grave affair, not for the faint-hearted,

The customers approach their drinking/the art of the cocktail studiously.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to say something like this:

> *Drinking here is **an earnest endeavor**, not for the corporeally or emotionally effete.*

or

> *Drinking here is **a dogged duty**, not for the digestively delicate.*

Answer (score 1):

- Drinking here is more than a mere recreation.
- Drinking here demands your full attention on the task at hand.
- Drinkers here approach their task with single-minded determination.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing an article, I would prefer to use the same words "serious and business" maybe in this way:
"Drinking here means- Business, and you better be serious about it"

Its just a fun way to write an article, if the tone can be friendly.